# How do I get a literal '%' in a mysql connector python query?

Tags: python, mysql, string-formatting, mysql-connector-python

Consider this code:

```py
def search(searchstr: str, limit: int=10, offset: int=0):
    csr = app.sql.cursor(dictionary=True)
    csr.execute("select username, fname, bio from followers where username like %%%s%% limit %d offset %d", (searchstr, limit, offset))
    return csr.fetchall()

search("j")
```

where `app.sql` is a reference to the connection object.

I would like it to execute something similiar to:
`select username, fname, bio from followers where username like %j% limit 10 offset 0`
but instead it always gives me the error:

```
  File "/---/user.py", line 67, in search
    csr.execute("select username, fname, avatarUrl, bio from followers where username like %%%s%% limit %d offset %d", (searchstr, limit, offset))
  File "/---/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 542, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong because

```py
>>> "%%%s%% %d %d" % ("j", 10, 0)
"%j% 10 0"
```

which is the expected output. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders do not work like copy and paste, you can't just place them *anywhere* and expect them to be understood. Even if it did work like that, in your case you'd end up with `like %foo%`, which is invalid SQL syntax.

You need to put one string placeholder into the query, and provide a string as argument which contains the `LIKE` wildcards:

```
csr.execute('... LIKE %s ...', (f'%{searchstr}%', ...))
```

In other words, you supply the `%` wildcards from Python, not from within the SQL statement.

Comment: I guess an additional problem is that the SQL connector only understands `%s` as a placeholder, not `%d`.